# How to change mainwindow's color to a specific color in pyqt/pyside?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I want a light blue color in my application, precicely #99ccff in html color codes. In my application, I have:

```
palette = QtGui.QPalette()
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.blue)
self.setPalette(palette)
```

Althought that changes the color to blue, it is not the type of blue that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QColor("#99ccff"))
```